# Converting int[][] to List<List<int>>

Tags: c#, arrays, list, jagged-arrays

I need to convert an array `int[][]` to `List<List<int>>`. Is it possible and how?

`Array[index].Length` can be 0.

First, i tried to do like this: `List<List<int>> ListName = new List<List<int>>(ArrayName);` but it didn't work. Then, I tried to use LINQ like  `List<List<int>> ListName = ArrayName.OfType<List<int>>().ToList();`  but it also didn't work. I searched in internet about this, but everywhere articles are saying about converting `int[]` to `List<int>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*articles are saying about converting `int[]` to `List<int>`*

That's the right idea, but you need to do it for the inner and outer arrays. Something like this:

```
var newList = new List<List<int>>(originalList.Length);

foreach (var item in originalList)
{
    newList.Add(new List<int>(item));
}
```

That should get you what you need!

Answer (score 0):

how about this..

```
int[][] array = new int[][] {
    new int[] { 1, 2 },
    new int[] { 3, 4, 5 },
    new int[] { 6 }
};

List<List<int>> list = array.Select(row => row.ToList()).ToList();
```

:-)